# I deleted the css content of a webapp, can I retrieve it?

Tags: eclipse

I was building a GUI to change the css on my website and I did something bad which lead to the content of every css file to be deleted. All my css are now empty. Is there a way to get it back ?

I believe the answer is no if I didn't use git but who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file still exists right click on it and select 'Replace With > Local History'. This will let you choose from the local history that Eclipse has (if any). You can also use 'Replace With > Previous from Local History' to just choose the most recent version.

If the file no longer exists then right click on the folder and choose 'Restore from Local History' to see the deleted files that Eclipse has.

Local history is only retained for a few days (configurable in the preferences).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a local history as well if I'm not mistaking. Not using eclipse anymore but I think you just have to right click the folder from which you want to restore something and then choose local history.